# Null Pointer Exception when calling web service from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services

I am trying to write a multi-threaded webservice that calls 4 webservices each from a thread. When I try to call a webservice directly it works. But when I try to call from a thread it throws a NullPointerException. Any Ideas on this?

```
@WebService(serviceName = "Negotiator")
public class Negotiator implements Runnable{
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/Negotiate4/Negotiate4.wsdl")
private Negotiate4_Service service_3;
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/Negotiate3/Negotiate3.wsdl")
private Negotiate3_Service service_2;
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/Negotiate2/Negotiate2.wsdl")
private Negotiate2_Service service_1;
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/Negotiate1/Negotiate1.wsdl")
private Negotiate1_Service service;

private String ret[] = new String[10];
private Thread t[] = new Thread[10];

/**
 * This is a sample web service operation
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
    try {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Negotiator(),"prov1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Negotiator(),"prov2");
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new Negotiator(),"prov3");
    Thread t4 = new Thread(new Negotiator(),"prov4");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    }
    catch(java.lang.InterruptedException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception: "+e);
    }
    String retString = "";
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        retString = retString + ret[i];
    }
    return "Hello " + retString + " !";
}

 @Override
public void run()
{
    Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.println("Inside run "+ th.getName());
    switch (th.getName()) {
        case "prov1":
            ret[0] = negotiate("Hi1");
            break;
        case "prov2":
            ret[1] = negotiate_1("Hi2");
            break;
        case "prov3":
            ret[2] = negotiate_2("Hi3");
            break;
        default:
            ret[3] = negotiate_3("Hi4");
            break;
    }
}

private String negotiate(java.lang.String name) {

    org.prov1.Negotiate1 port1 = service.getNegotiate1Port();
    return port1.negotiate(name);
}

private String negotiate_1(java.lang.String name) {

    org.prov2.Negotiate2 port2 = service_1.getNegotiate2Port();
    return port2.negotiate(name);
}

private String negotiate_2(java.lang.String name) {

    org.prov3.Negotiate3 port3 = service_2.getNegotiate3Port();
    return port3.negotiate(name);
}

private String negotiate_3(java.lang.String name) {

    org.prov4.Negotiate4 port4 = service_3.getNegotiate4Port();
    return port4.negotiate(name);
}
}
```

When I try to call the negotiate operation from inside the hello method it works. But when negotiate is called from inside run() I get a NullPointerException. Please help.

Comment: Identifying the line where the NPE is thrown would help - is it all four negotiate_x calls?.

Comment: Where is service, service_1,... set?

Comment: @laune Yes. The exception is thrown whenever I call negotiate, negotiate_1, etc. that is, first line of each 'case' in run method. I don't know where service_x is set since most of that code is generated by NetBeans. But anyway it works if I call negotiate outside run() method. So why doesn't it work inside run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that `@WebServiceRef` is processed in current thread and most probably container keeps thread local reference through a proxy. If you are using Java EE7 container you could try to use `ManagedExecutorService` to call methods, but not sure will it work or not. Everything is depends by whom and how the service classes are initialized. Provide more details about the setup.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! ManagedExecutorService, Callable and Future solved it. I never knew we had to "pass" parameters to a thread and that threads "returned" values.